# How to Obtain a Debug Signature for Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I obtain my projects debug signature to use with a Google API?

I have opened `keystore.debug` and cannot read that file. I have also opened in eclipse `Windows>Preferences>Android>Build` and tried to use the **SHA1** value from that window, but I believe this is the wrong method.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command in dos :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin>keytool -v -list -keystore c:\debuge.keystore
```

It will ask for your password: It is android

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the [signatures](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/Signature.html) (generaly just one) of the current application package using:

```
static public Signature[] getSignatures(final Context ctx) {
    try {
        final PackageInfo pinfo = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        return pinfo.signatures;
    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then, you can dump or display the encoded Signature as an ASCII text with [`Signature.toCharsString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/Signature.html#toCharsString%28%29). When you will have this string, you should be able to check at runtime whether you are using the debug certificate or not.